# SQL Password Policy Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am sure, someone must have had this problem before. I work in an organization where the Audit asks us developers to enforce password policy in our applications. We have created SQL Logins and enforced password policy.  The problem that we faced recently is when the password is expired, the SQL administrator had to unlock each login manually.
And the users complaint that they didn't get any sort of reminder that they should change their passwords.
How can we achieve this target? What we want is to be able to enforce password policy (Password length, expiration) and be able to notify user atleast 15 days prior to the expiration of his password

EDIT 1
my applications are desktop based and also web based. Desktop based applications use SQL logins to validate themselves while asp.net Intranet website use users created by ASP.NET Website Administration tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to get when user passwords will expire as a part of SQL Agent job or SSIS package (if you need more complex processing):

```
USE [master]
GO
SELECT [name] AS [sa]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'PasswordLastSetTime') AS [PasswordLastResetDT]
      ,DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT([datetime],LOGINPROPERTY([name],'PasswordLastSetTime')),GETDATE()) AS [DaysUntilExpiration]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'BadPasswordCount') AS [BadPasswordCount]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'BadPasswordTime') AS [BadPasswordDT]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'HistoryLength') AS [HistoryLength]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'IsExpired') AS [IsExpired]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'IsLocked') AS [IsLocked]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'IsMustChange') AS [IsMustChange]
      ,LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'LockoutTime') AS [LockoutTime]
FROM [sys].[sql_logins]
GROUP BY [name]
```

After that you somehow need to correlate user names and their passwords and send email before the password expires.

Comment: what about those user names that were created using ASP.NET website administration tool

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate what your problem is. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can select logins by this query

```
select * from sys.sql_logins where is_expiration_checked=1
```

And then check [LOGINPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx) to get `DaysUntilExpiration`. Just make a service which will be checking passwords daily and notify users by email.

Comment: is this a normal procedure? i mean, does every develop has to do it where audit requires such criteria? also, how would i check for password length and criteria?

Comment: wll thath depends on how your system is built. Whether you allow your users to directly access to db or not. I use special intraned site to allow users change passwords, and have my own provider of exoiration. Which allows me control expiration and password complexity easily.

Comment: can u show me any code of your work if you don't mind please?